# Extend pixi.js sprite an accessing parent's properties in constructor

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

I'm attempting to extend pixi.js' sprite class and set it's position.x property in my child class constructor

```
var Ship = function(x, y, image, focused) {
    PIXI.Sprite.fromImage.call(this, image);

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.image = image;
    this.focused = typeof focused != 'undefined' ? focused : false;

    this.position.x = window.width/2;
};

Ship.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Sprite.fromImage.prototype);

Ship.prototype.constructor = Ship;
```

but, I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined" on

```
this.position.x = window.width/2;
```

I believe that I'm not able to access parent class's properties until after the Object.create() call... So what's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ship.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Sprite.prototype);

should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. For the record, I had to change both instances of
`PIXI.Sprite.fromImage`
for it to work.

Comment: @saoyr5 I don't understand what I have to write instead of `PIXI.Sprite.fromImage.call(this, image);` to make it work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @alMAC I think you need PIXI.Sprite.call(this);

Comment: @saoyr5 but then how do you call `fromImage(image)` ?

Comment: @aIMAC I'm not quite sure because my code has changed since then, but I'm pretty sure you can just call: `this.fromImage(image)` inside the constructor since fromImage() is a method of PIXI.Sprite.

Comment: @saoyr5 Thanks I will try :)