# PIXI.js SpriteSheet - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_parentID')

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js

I was trying to use [PIXI.js](https://pixijs.com/) to create an animation on the web. I needed to load a spritesheet with `PIXI.Loader.Shared.add()` and then use it with `PIXI.AnimatedSprite()` to create the animation.

**This is my code with bugs**:

```
PIXI.Loader.Shared.add(`assets/0.json`).load(sceneLoad);

function sceneLoad() {
  const scene = new PIXI.Container();
  const s = PIXI.Loader.Shared.resources["assets/0.json"].spritesheet.textures;

  let eyes = [s['Eyes.png'], s['ClosedEyes.png']]; 
  eyes = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(eyes);
  scene.addChild(eyes); // Where the error occurs
}
```

**This is the error I had**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_parentID')
    at e.addChild (pixi.min.js:8)
    at sceneLoad (scenes.js:40)
    at t.dispatch (pixi.min.js:8)
    at e._onComplete (pixi.min.js:8)
    at pixi.min.js:8
    at s (pixi.min.js:8)
    at e.use (pixi.min.js:8)
    at pixi.min.js:8
    at pixi.min.js:8
```

I checked [this](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/7004) thread with the same error. But it was about a different PIXI.js method. And I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140597/extend-pixi-js-sprite-an-accessing-parents-properties-in-constructor) thread with the same error. But the answer wasn't explained and was about a different PIXI.js method.

This is the [spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9vW.jpg) I was using with its JSON:

```
{"frames": {
"ClosedEyes.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":500,"y":0,"w":500,"h":700},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":500,"h":700},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
},
"Eyes.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":700,"w":500,"h":700},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":500,"h":700},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
}},
"meta": {
    "app": "https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "image": "1.png",
    "format": "RGBA8888",
    "size": {"w":1373,"h":1482},
    "scale": "1",
    "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:f87f23b00c6d9d315163af7aa5edde4e:c4a362a6939011366e8ebf2df4b161e1:f91cade670d3cd0da3efe30dce0ef325$"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at the PIXI.js [documentation](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Spritesheet.html) on `PIXI.SpriteSheet` again, I saw this example:

```
new PIXI.Sprite(sheet.textures["image.png"]);
```

**They created a `PIXI.Sprite()` object** from the objects under

```
PIXI.Loader.Shared.resources["assets/0.json"].spritesheet.textures
```

Whereas, I did not in the code above. So I modified my code to create the `PIXI.Sprite()` object. Here is the working code:

```
PIXI.Loader.Shared.add(`assets/0.json`).load(sceneLoad);

function sceneLoad() {
  const scene = new PIXI.Container();
  const s = PIXI.Loader.Shared.resources["assets/0.json"].spritesheet.textures;

  let eyes = [new PIXI.Sprite(s['Eyes.png']), new PIXI.Sprite(s['ClosedEyes.png'])]; 
  eyes = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(eyes);
  scene.addChild(eyes); // Where the error occurs
}
```